# wifi issue on samsung- galaxy-s-duos

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-duos

My mobile device doesn't detect any Wi-fi signal even though there is an active network available in the area.
Can anyone help me to find a solution to this problem??
Device: Samsung galaxy-s-duos.
android version: jellybean

Comment: Did you try factory resetting your phone?

Comment: @TimoS Yes I did the factory resetting, still its not working..

Comment: Did it work before?

Comment: @TimoS yes it was working till 14 months from purchase date. Do you have any other solution for it??

Comment: You can try flashing a custom rom for your device.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to try to restart your phone. Check your settings and make sure everything is on in the wifi settings.

Keep in mind that if the wifi network is hidden, it won't show up - you have to manually enter its name and password to be able to connect.

Comment: I tried that also its not working! I guess its a hardware problem!!